Vue's ref doesn't maintain types of nested private properties
This problem occurs both with arrays and objects. Using shallowRef instead of ref solves it but I often need deep reactivity. Now I use casting, but I'm not happy with it. What's the best way to address this problem?
class Bar {
    private val = 1;
}

class Foo {
    private bar = new Bar();
}

const fooRef = ref(new Foo());

const foo: Foo = fooRef.value; // Property bar is missing in type {} but required in type Foo
const bar = fooRef.value.bar; // Property bar does not exist on type {}

const baz = ref([new Foo()]); 
const z = baz.value[0].bar.val; // Property bar does not exist on type {}

Packages I use:
"typescript": "^5.6.3",
"vue": "^3.5.12",


bar is private, it's not expected to be accessed. Vue reactivity is unfriendly to classes, I'd advise against using them together in general, there's rarely a real necessity to do this. The best way would be to use plain objects, this is the case reactivity api was primarily made for

@EstusFlask I cannot change the majority of files used in the project.

Then consider explaining your case in details, so an answer that addresses it could be given. There's no problem in general because you wouldn't care about the existence of "bar", it's private

The problem is that I get errors in my IDE because of type mismatch, as in the first assignment, which doesn't even mention bar

Generally speaking it breaks the whole idea of type safety.

What is the problem with relying on inferred type like const foo = fooRef.value instead of foo: Foo? It would be the correct one as it contains public members

The problem is that all the places in the codebase where it's used are alrealy waiting for the Foo type.

The problem is what you mentioned, type safety. fooRef.value is not guaranteed to be Foo type, at least because of ref unwrapping (it's also a proxy that may not work exactly as Foo instance depending on what you do with it). If you believe the type is correct, you have to use type assertions where Foo is expected, which you probably already do. Or refactor code to rely more on duck typing, i.e. expect something like ExtractPublic. Currently it looks like the problem is that code was written without keeping in mind how it will work with vue reactivity

@EstusFlask The code of the project was written using Vue 2 and now is being transferred to Vue 3. It relies heavily upon types based on classes, so it seems the only option for me is to use assertions.

I see. Generally in a case like this one it makes sense to distinguish between class instances and types as suggested, i.e. TFoo = ExtractPublic, or the opposite, class Foo implements IFoo ... . Private class members are often used to prevent unwanted duck typing, but here it seems to be adverse effect. Any way, assertions are ok when they are necessary

ref creates deeply reactive object that does ref unwrapping, and ref type works by extracting public members, this is a way for it to implement unwrapping. This is important for class types because their compatibility requires their private members to match.
So it's expected that fooRef.value type may not be Foo, at least when the class implementation uses reactivity API. This requires to use type assertion when a developer is certain that the type is correct.
This can be done at the time where a value is consumed:
const foo = fooRef.value as Foo;

Or when a ref is created:
const fooRef = ref(new Foo()) as Ref<Foo>;

Which is not the same as ref<Foo>(new Foo()), the latter works the same way as ref(new Foo()).

You could remove private (maybe also protected props) and thus using only the public interface:
Playground
type Public<T extends object> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} extends infer A ? A : never;
let foo: Public<Foo>;

foo = fooRef.value;

